# Gotham Narrow and Google Yrsa commonly available alternatives?

Tags: fonts, windows

I need fonts that are commonly available on desktop platforms (Windows/Mac, base system + MS Office) that are similar to Gotham Narrow and Google Yrsa.
I've seen mention that Arial is similar looking to Gotham but I don't know.
Thanks.

Comment: Check out the Word fonts here: [link](https://www.microsoft.com/typography/fonts/product.aspx?PID=163). And the system fonts here: [link](http://www.patrickpatoray.com/index.php?Page=100). Not sure if they are 100% up to date, but neither are the users' computers. None of them are really "similar" to the fonts mentioned. They will never get the same overall look. I've had the same trouble with a customer who wanted to make stuff themselves, with the same professional look as my work for them. What is your reason to ask?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. The reason we ask is due to the comment in the below answer "whoever gets your document also needs to have the fonts installed." We collaborate with various third parties with a lot of our reports, and we would like some kind of consistency with overall design and look of other materials (website, published reports, etc.) Links are useful but quite old now. Thank you for your time. It seems like this might be difficult or impossible to accomplish. Easiest solution may be looking at different "base" fonts for our designs.

Answer (score 1):

Although Arial is similar to Gotham Narrow, it has attributes which are very dissimilar, notably the tails of lower-case letters like *a, e, g, s*. Capital letters are probably a little too wide, too. A better alternative might be **Segoe UI,** which is probably available on recent Windows systems.

Here's Gotham Narrow, Arial Nova and Segoe UI. Unfortunately it wasn't possible to make everything exactly the same size, but it's possible to see that Segoe UI is very similar in shape to Gotham Narrow.

[image: Comparison]

Comment: Your image here doesn’t seem right—none of the three fonts in it is Gotham Narrow.

Comment: The first line _IS_ Gotham Narrow... :/

Comment: @Pepe Well, it certainly isn’t [Hoefler & Co.’s Gotham Narrow](https://www.typography.com/fonts/gotham/inside/gotham-narrow), that much is certain. [Here is a direct comparison](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qckzn.png) between the first line in Andrew’s picture (top) and Gotham Narrow Book (bottom) where you can see quite clearly that they are very different. I can’t for the life of me think of what the first one is, but it’s definitely not Gotham Narrow, unless there’s another font called Gotham Narrow that I’m unaware of.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Man, you're totally right! Indeed, that's not Gotham Narrow, the glyphs are different. :o

Answer (score 0):

[Roboto](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Roboto) from Google Fonts is free and pretty close to Gotham Narrow. Certainly not in the same league as Gotham is a top-end commercial font, but give it a try.

Please note, using non-system fonts means whoever gets your document also needs to have the fonts installed.

Comment: Roboto is free, but sadly it's not "commonly available on desktop platforms".